# Abrir URL dentro de la aplicación Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Mi problema es el siguiente, he creado un botón que llama haciendo clic en un URL de la página, y cuando hago clic en él se abre el navegador. Me gustaría abrir dentro de la propia aplicación. Alguien me puede ayudar ?

---

**Main Activity**

```
public void btnSite (View View) {

    String url = "http://google.com.br/";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

¿Qué configuración debo usar para abrir dentro de la aplicación?

Comment: En ese caso necesitas usar el componente webview y establecer la url de tu del sitio web con webview.loadUrl(urlWeb); https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

Answer (score 6):

Tienes que crear un custom WebView (WebView Personalizado), esto para poder abrir dentro de la misma aplicación, este es un ejemplo:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);

        webView.loadUrl("http://es.stackoverflow.com");

    }

}
```

Layout `activity_webview.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    />
```

Lo que tienes que realizar es simplemente cargar la `Activity` (no olvides registrarla en tu AndroidMnifest.xml),

```
 Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, WebViewActivity.class);
 startActivity(myIntent);
```

Esta es una imagen de como cargaría el WebView dentro de tu aplicación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto también puedes implementarlo en un fragmento.

Encontré otro **[tutorial](https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/)** (inglés) donde puedes ver como implementar el Custom WebView.

Comment: Es importante recalcar, que         webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
solo debe activarse para sitios en los que necesita ejecutar una función javascript, si no lo haces, no agregar esta linea

Comment: Si Maguz, decido siempre agregar el habilitar el .JS, la razón, es que alguna ocasión en SO en inglés un OP me comentaba que no "funcionaba", así asegura que la página que cargue el WebView pueda tener su completa funcionalidad.

Answer (score 1):

Hay dos formas de hacer esto.

1) Usar WebView

layout.xml

```
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

Java

```
 public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, WebViewActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
          }
```

2) O crear el intent para lanzarlo al browser.

xml

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent">
android:id="@+id/button_su" android:onClick="goToUrl"></Button>
    </LinearLayout>
```

java

```
 public void goToUrl () {
        Uri uriUrl = Uri.parse("www.google.com");
        Intent launchBrowser = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uriUrl);
        startActivity(launchBrowser);
    }
```

Espero igual te sirva los siguientes links.

https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5026349/how-to-open-a-website-when-a-button-is-clicked-in-android-application

Comment: el pregunta solo por el webview, ya que especificó que desea ver el sitio adentro de la aplicación

Answer (score 1):

layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/wvWeb" />
</LinearLayout>
```

In your Activity

**VARIABLES GLOBALES**

```
ProgressDialog dialog = null;
     public static WebView wvFacebook;
        final String url="https://www.facebook.com/";
```

**DENTRO DE TU ACTIVITY**

```
dialog = ProgressDialog.show(getActivity(), "",
                "Cargando...", true);

        if (checkConnectivity()) {
            wvFacebook = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.wvWeb);
            WebSettings webSettings = wvFacebook.getSettings();
            wvFacebook.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            wvFacebook.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient() {

                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }

            });
            wvFacebook.loadUrl(url);
        } else {
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Sin conexión a Internet...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                ;
            }, 8000);
        }
```

**CHECAR INTERNET**

```
private boolean checkConnectivity() {
        boolean enabled = true;

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo info = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if ((info == null || !info.isConnected() || !info.isAvailable())) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Problemas con su conexión a Internet...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            enabled = false;
        }
        return enabled;
    }
```

//ESTA ES IMPORTANTE PARA LA NAVEGACION

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

    }
```

//Si quiere controlar la navegación hacia atrás, es decir, cuando navegas dentro de tu Webview, y quieres dar back sin salirte del Web usa esto:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {


            if (wvFacebook.canGoBack()) {
                wvFacebook.goBack();

    }
```